# Linux syscall + cross compilation

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have to use some syscalls from the custom Linux kernel. The project is cross compiling on host system and then running on target board. The problem is - the host system doesn't implement those syscalls. I have compilation error:

`error: 'BSP_SYS_read_new_data' was not declared in this scope syscall(BSP_SYS_read_new_data, LEFT, m_buffer.get(), m_buffer_size);`

I can use something like:

```
#define BSP_SYS_read_new_data <xxx>
```

where  comes from syscall.tbl from target system kernel sources.
I'm on right way?

Comment: Consider instead conditional compilation around the call (surrounding the call with `#ifdef DEVBOARD` and `#endif`) or moving the board-specific functions off to a board support library (one cpp file for the devboard and one for PC hardware and a header that both cpp implement, even if the PC implementation does nothing) and let the linker handle it.

Comment: and build accessory library directly on board?

Comment: Are you compiling against the host's kernel headers, instead of the ones for your target's kernel?  That's consistent with your symptoms.

Comment: Ignore me. I misread. @TobySpeight has the correct intterpretation. I though you wanted toe code to run on both PC and target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syscall header file is generated by running a grep script over the kernel source .tbl. If you don't have the header file you can run the script yourself. If you have the appropriate header files for your target system, you need to somehow arrange that those headers are used for this build in preference to your build-host's copy. In theory you should be surplanting all of /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu (or whatever your host uses) with your target's version, which should be 1 build path entry.